# Scala list columns dynamically drop the columns from the list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark scala code which performs as below:

```
         val ua_list = List()
            for (a <- a_col_names)
                if (some condition ) {
                       ua_list  :+ (a)
```

Now i am calling the list in dataframe to drop  all the columns from the list

```
             val df_d = df_p.drop(ua_list.map(name => col(name)): _*)   

              The error i am facing is no `: _*' annotation allowed here (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
```

Not sure what exactly the issue is ?  Any suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `_*` means all columns in the list, no need to `map` and get each column.

simply you can do like below.

```
df_p.drop(ua_list : _*)
```

Full example :

```
import spark.implicits._
  val df = Seq(
    (123, "ITA", 1475600500, 18.0),
    (123, "ITA", 1475600500, 18.0),
    (123, "ITA", 1475600516, 19.0)
  ).toDF("Value", "Country", "Timestamp", "Sum")


  df.show
  val ua_list = List("Value", "Timestamp")

  df.drop(ua_list: _*).show
```

Result :

```
+-----+-------+----------+----+
|Value|Country| Timestamp| Sum|
+-----+-------+----------+----+
|  123|    ITA|1475600500|18.0|
|  123|    ITA|1475600500|18.0|
|  123|    ITA|1475600516|19.0|
+-----+-------+----------+----+

+-------+----+
|Country| Sum|
+-------+----+
|    ITA|18.0|
|    ITA|18.0|
|    ITA|19.0|
+-------+----+
```